# Setting up Cloudinary plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, tinymce-3

I am trying to follow the steps for setting up the Cloudinary plugin for TinyMCE text editor in Rails documented here: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_tinymce.

> This plugin replaces the image button of TinyMCE to allow you to add and manipulate images from Cloudinary's cloud-based media library.

1. Does this mean that this plugin allows the user to upload an image to the TinyMCE text editor? What should happen when the user clicks on the image button of the TinyMCE text editor?
2. When following the steps outlined in the documentation, the pop-up that appears after clicking on the image button of the TinyMCE text editor is empty. Does the body of `cloudinaryimage/image.htm` need to be filled with content? Must I include my own form and input, or is this a sign that something went wrong when I tried to set up the plugin?